# Confused about CMake versions, need CMake 3.5 but CMake's site can only find CMake 3.27

Tags: c, cmake

I am told that I need to use CMake version 3.5 but I can only find 3.27, on CMake's GitHub the newest version is 3.27, on their website the newest version is 3.26. I can find release notes on CMake 3.5 but no code for it. Does being on a windows machine affect this?

I know that this may be a trivial question for some but I don't understand this.

Comment: Why do you want an older version? Because you're on a system that has an older version and you want documentation for it? Do you have `git` on your system? Have you done `git clone` so you can do other commands like `git log`? Then, you could do `git checkout` on the correct revision for 3.5 Also, I'm not familiar with CMake's use of version numbers. But, with the minor version bump, it may just be bug fixes, so 3.26 is just fine for 3.5

Comment: @CraigEstey so if i am understanding this correctly the version numbers count up like 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11, . . . 3.20, 3.21, . . . 3.27 not like 3.07, 3.08, 3.09, etc.

Comment: "I can only find verson 3.27". The officially current release version is 3.26; 3.27 is currently in the release candidate state. If you go to "older releases" available releases seem to go back until version 2.4.8 though: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases?page=21 (and even older ones, if you look at the ones on `cmake.org` linked on the download page...

Comment: How are the "alternatives" for counting mentioned in your previous comment different though? The convention for version number comparisons is you take a look at the numbers before the first period, then the ones between the first and second period, and so on until you find the first place where the numbers are different. At that point the version with the smaller number is the older version. E.g. `2.3.4` is older than `3.3.4`, `2.3.4` is older than `2.99.4`, `2.3.4` is older than `2.3.1111115`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at a CMake project's `cmake_minimum_required` call and it says `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)`, that means you should be able to use version equal to or greater than 3.5.

That being said, if you want to install past versions of CMake, [the downloads page](https://cmake.org/download/) is pretty clear about where you can get them. The "Alternative Binary Releases" section points to https://apt.kitware.com/, https://snapcraft.io/cmake, and https://pypi.org/project/cmake/. The "Older Releases" section points to https://cmake.org/files and https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases.

Answer (score 0):

> ### Older Releases
>
> | **Host** | **Link** |
> | --- | --- |
> | kitware | https://cmake.org/files |
> | github | https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases |

src: https://cmake.org/download

So for CMake 3.5 => https://cmake.org/files/v3.5/